# Script to clean/terminate sleepy Mysql Connections to RDS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, monitoring

I have a ruby on rails app, running to ec2 ubuntu instance and running Mysql database on RDS. I started monitoring RDS instance using mysql workbench. I figured out that, I have more then 35 sleep connections from ruby on rails app to RDS. Which is making my app too slow, I want to come up with a script or some thing like which would keep an eye on the number of RDS sleepy connections and terminate them periodically.

Whenever I try to run a script it say's Time out exception.

Let me know.

Comment: Why would inactive connections make your application "too slow"? They're not doing anything. They're nearly zero cost. The connection time incurred in reactivating these connections will almost certainly make your application slow.

Comment: I am not able to make new connections, thats the problem it says the max pool connection is 10 or something like that

Comment: How did you realized that your application is slow? Are you sure that MySQL is bottle-neck? Btw, max_pool_conn=10 is too small (if you have a lot of online users). Let us see your original problem.

Comment: I always have 100-200 concurrent users online and to run my back end scripts I get such errors sometimes. basically its an e-commerce application

Comment: What errors? Why slow? Could you please expand your question because we are trying to guess

Comment: @JeevanDongre I am with tadman and ravnur here.  Having connections in a sleep state in and of itself should not be a problem. Try upping your connection pool to 100 max connections and see what happens then.